# Google adsense on the fly

Tags: google-maps-api-3, adsense

I am building a web based route planning software using google maps. I decided to register for google adsense and got approved. The website looks like a desktop software which to a significant extent may contradicts with the google adsense policy. The problem I want to describe can be devided on three questions:

1. Their policy says that you can not have more than three ad units on a page. Does it means that I can not have more than 3 ads? For example I create three ad units but one of them I use on 4 different places.

The reason I want this is because the ads are not visible except the user clicks a button and a popup window ( with controls and navigation ) with ad on it appears. So if I have 10 different popup windows I want in all of them to have an ad unit. Has anyone done something like that before?

2. If the answer to the above question where I ask if I can have 3 ad units with more than three ads on the page ( which are not visible at the same time ) is NO then is there a way where I can programmatically remove and insert ads to particular div based on some event ( like user clicks a button ) ?
3. I also implemented an ad using the maps api but in the adsense console it does say the ad is active ( no matter that ads are being served ). This confuses me because the other ad units which are not inserted by the maps api are labeled as active in the adsense administration console.

Sorry for putting three different questions but simply they are related to a practical example of what i did and things are not clear how exactly it works.

P.S.

You can check the website [routeplan24.com](http://routeplan24.com) in order to get a better perception of what I mean. When it loads click on "Route settings" to bring a popup window.

Comment: You really should add a TL;DR

Comment: TL? DR? What is that?

Comment: Too Long; Didn't Read: Used to indicate that what follows is a summary of the overly long text.
It can also be useful to clarify.